# android list items simple TextView change to initial state after scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I am making an restaurant app which consists of food items list in which users can add or subtract food items no. My problem is whenever add button is clicked it increase that food item value but after scrolling list down or up. Its value changes to its initial state. I have searched every question regarding this on Stackoverflow and on many other websites but nothing helped me.
I have tried ViewHolder, setfocuschangelistener etc etc
I know problem is recycling stuff done by android please can anyone tell me what should i do to solve my problem

Here is my custom adapter class:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

String costing;
ImageView add;
int totalCost;
loggedIn loggedIn;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] foods) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row ,foods);
}

static class ViewHolder{

    TextView foodItem;
    TextView noOfFoodItem;
    ImageView minus;
    ImageView add;
    TextView cost;

}



@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    if(convertView==null) {

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.foodItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.foodItem);
        holder.cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);
        holder.minus = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.minus);
        holder.noOfFoodItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noOfFoodItem);
        holder.add = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

    }

    try{

        String[] foodItems = {"Burger               ","Pizza                 ","Cold Drinks      ",
                "Coffee               ","Burger               ","Pizza                 ",
                "Cold Drinks      ","Coffee               ","Burger               ",
                "Pizza                 ","Cold Drinks      ","Coffee               ","Burger               ",
                "Pizza                 ",
                "Cold Drinks      ","Coffee                "};
        holder.foodItem.setText(foodItems[position]);

        String[] costs = {"Rs.70","Rs.80","Rs.70","Rs.80","Rs.70","Rs.80","Rs.70","Rs.80","Rs.70","Rs.80","Rs.70","Rs.80"};
        holder.cost.setText(costs[position]);

        holder.minus.setImageResource(R.drawable.minus);

        holder.noOfFoodItem.setText("0");

        holder.add.setImageResource(R.drawable.add);

    }catch (Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Getting items selected of any food item
            if(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString().equals("9")){

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Maximum limit reached!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.noOfFoodItem.setText("9");

            }else
             holder.noOfFoodItem.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())+1));

        }
    });

    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString().equals("0")){

                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Do you need some medical attention?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.noOfFoodItem.setText("0");

            }else{

            holder.noOfFoodItem.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())-1));
        }
        }
    });

    return convertView;


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to keep the value for each item in the list from being recycled. You can do this by using HashMap and putting noOfFoodCount in hasmap with position as key and food count as value.

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding or subtracting the value from the current text.You have to create an arraylist for saving these count.

Create an arraylist like `ArrayList<Integer> count=new ArrayList<Integer>;`
Then while adding,

```
 holder.add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //Getting items selected of any food item
        if(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString().equals("9")){

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Maximum limit reached!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.noOfFoodItem.setText("9");

            count.add(9);

        }else {
           holder.noOfFoodItem.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())+1));
           count.add(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())+1);
     }
    }
});
```

And in case of decreasing the count,

```
holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString().equals("0")){

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Do you need some medical attention?",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.noOfFoodItem.setText("0");

              count.add(0);

        }else{
           holder.noOfFoodItem.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())-1));
           count.add(Integer.parseInt(holder.noOfFoodItem.getText().toString())-1);
     }
    }
});
```

Hope you understood.

Comment: Thanks for answering but i didn't understand you properly can you please tell me in brief

Comment: adding and subtracting is done in else statement not if statement you have added code in if statement.

Comment: What i have done is created an arraylist and set its value according to i need and after that i set that value to text. It changes its value but same problem when i scroll it is again set to 0

Comment: I have copied your code and try again but its not working

Answer (score 0):

add a global variable

```
List<String> foodItems;
```

change you constructor to

```
 public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] foods) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row ,foods);
     foodItems=Arrays.asList(foods);
    }
```

and modify your add button onClickListerner else block to

```
else{
    foodItems.add("add your item name here");
    holder.noOfFoodItem.setText(foodItems.size());

    }
```

let me know if you need any clarity

Comment: Now after using your code whenever i click add button my app crashes